# Translate UIImagePickerController camera preview in Swift 3

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, swift3

In Swift 2, I used this to translate the camera preview down by 50px:

```
let translate: CGAffineTransform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0.0, y: 50.0)
self.imagePicker.cameraViewTransform = translate
```

As far as I can see, this line has no effect in Swift 3. How can I achieve the previous behaviour?

Comment: Anyone got anything for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been resolved in iOS 10.2.